# How to fix Curl error: Failed to connect to for proxies

Tags: php, curl, post

I'm trying to make a post request for an account creator website and I need to have a different IP each time so the captcha doesn't show up. So I tried setting a proxy by doing using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "https://188.166.213.255:3128");`. When I don't use the proxy setting it connects just fine but after refreshing the page 3-4 times, I get hit by a captcha. I wanted to bypass it by using the proxy but I keep getting a Failed to connect to [IP] port [port].

If it matters, my website is being hosted by namecheap.
Not sure if namecheap is blocking the connections.

I have tried over 1000+ proxies, I tried ones that I know work with a python program that I've used that does the same thing my site is going to do.

The full code I use:

```html
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "https://188.166.213.255:3128");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'SOCK5');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 12);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 12);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);;                                                                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $additional_headers);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    // this would be your first hint that something went wrong
    //echo $resultStatus."<br>";
    die('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

else {
    $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($resultStatus == 403 or $resultStatus == 200) {
        if (strpos($server_output, 'Captcha') !== false) {
            echo 'Failed to create account due to the Captcha.';
        } else {
            $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $conn = new mysqli(host, username, password, database);
            $sql  = "INSERT INTO Accounts (Name, Password, Date, Result) VALUES ('" . $username . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $date . "', '" . $server_output . "')";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "Account Created!";
                echo "<br>";
  echo "Username: " . $username . "";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Password: " . $password . "";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Response: " . $server_output . "";
  echo "<br>New Server";
            }
            
            else {
                echo "Rip: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }
        $worked = True;
    }
    
    else {
        die('Request failed: HTTP status code: ' . $resultStatus);
    }
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a working proxy address, you're properly connecting to it, and the webserver running the PHP script has access to it?

Comment: I have tried over 1000+ proxies, I tried ones that I know work with a python program that I've used that does the same thing my site is going to do.

Comment: The whole point of the CAPTCHA is to prevent you from doing exactly what you're trying to do. I don't think you'll find many of us willing to help you bypass somebody else's protection.

Comment: Fair enough, even if it wasn't part for the captcha, I still can't get proxies to work for my site and can't figure out why they don't work.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast I'm not sure about this proxy, but previous ones I have checked and they properly worked. I believe the php script has access to it?